# Binding of repeater not showing anything after getting 2nd set of products

Tags: asp.net

My Page_Load calls the following:

```
pnlProductWrapper.Visible = true;

pnlList2Column.Visible = true;
                rptList2Column.StartIndex = startIndex - 1;
                rptList2Column.NumItems = productsPerPage;
                rptList2Column.DataSource = UseManualProductList() ? lPage.LPageProducts.Values.ToList() : products;
                rptList2Column.DataBind()
```

on first page load, I see my repeater just fine and its products.  But we have a paging control.  When clicking next all it does is through a param up in the querystring and we grab it and requery to get more products.  So 2nd time around it comes to here again and I debugged and definitely verified that products above is what's being picked and set to the DataSource and after DataBind, rptList2Column has 6 records.  But when my page loads, the repeater is not showing up.

Here's some of my mark-up:

```
<div id="ProductWrapper">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlList2Column" Visible="false" runat="server">
     <xx:xxRepeater ID="rptList2Column" EnableViewState="false" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <td valign="top" align="center" width="150px" style="padding-top:5px">
            <div>
            <a href="<%#xxx(Container.DataItem)%>"><img src="<%#xxx(Container.DataItem)%>" border="0" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p><a href="<%#(xxx(Container.DataItem))%>"><%#(Container.DataItem).Name%></a></p>
            <p><%#xxx(((xxx)Container.DataItem))%></p>                                
            </div>                                
        </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </xxx:xxx>                 
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

this is a custom repeater and I have 3 on the page, each wrapped with a panel.  The first repeater is setup just like this and has no problems.  So I don't see why this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some problems with the ViewState. Be sure to use!Page.IsPostBack when necassary. Don't store your data in the ViewState AND bind tge repeater on each load.

Comment: Viewstate is disabled on the repeater.  Also, I am binding the repeater on each Page_load

Comment: The problem is not that I'm not binding every time.  It's hitting that binding code EVERY TIME when I refresh my page which is what I want and it's setting the properties to valid values on load.

Comment: And you wouldn't want to use !Page.IsPostback because I'm calling this code in Page_Load and I want it to hit that binding every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had set an index wrong on the repeater.  My fault.